# How to check internet connection continuously in Xamarin.Android Native?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

My application is completely based on internet and it does not work without it, when the internet is not available or it is slow my application is getting stopped unfortunately.
I tried to implement try, catch but it is not helping me out as it is not throwing any exception, then I thought that I have to check the internet connectivity continuously till the app is running and stop any activity from performing and set a popup to connect to the internet.

I am able to get the popup whenever I call a method which has the following code inside it,

```C#
 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
                if (networkInfo == null)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alert.SetTitle("Network");
                    alert.SetMessage("Please turn of your Wifi or Mobile Data From Settings");
                    alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionSettings);
                        StartActivity(intent);
                    });

                    alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) => {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Cancelled!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        Finish();
                    });

                    Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                    dialog.Show();
```

But I am unable to get the connection checked continuously, So Can some one Please help me to complete get this functionality in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to monitor network changes.

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" })]
    [Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action != ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction)
                return;

             //Check if is connected and raise a custom event or store 
             //the current in a static global variable

        }
    }
}
```

> **In Android 7.0**, you need to remove IntentFilter from the class and register the receiver.

```
var receiver = new ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver();
Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction));
```

### Another option is to use the ConnectivityPlugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin , which is easier to use.

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += HandleConnectivityChanged;


void HandleConnectivityChanged (object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // You can check the network status in 
    //e.IsConnected
}
```

Note that The **ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** and **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE** permissions are required.

Comment: FYI: Any app targeting Android 7.0 (or above) that BroadcastReceiver will not work, you need to use RegisterReceiver instead and remove the manifest intent filters

Comment: I think this is for the forms not for the Native. I am trying to implement it but it is not getting any references for OnReceive event.
If this is for the Native then can you please explain how to implement in a native droid application

Comment: can you help me make the above code work when only required in a activity.
or the link for different properties for implementation where the complete description is given